# почему не подключается хедер к файлу,на который перехожу по ссылке?

Tags: php, html

------content------

```
<?php
   require_once 'views/header.php';
?>

<html>
   <a href="views/content/content2.php"> content </a>   
</html>
```

в логах пишет Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'views/content/header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/targetspanish2.com/views/content/content2.php on line 2

------content2------

```
<?php
   require_once 'views/header.php';
?>

<html>
   <a href="views/content/content.php"> content2 </a>   
</html>
```

Comment: какой код, так невозможно понять?

Comment: во, добавилось)

Comment: ну так написано файла нет.

Comment: у вас текущий скрипт в `views/content` а хэдер во `views/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

так должно работать

```
<?php
   require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'header.php');
?>

<html>
   <a href="views/content/content.php"> content2 </a>   
</html>
```

Comment: ад с переносом на другой сервер будет обеспечен. `include_path` править надо и пути относительные писать, вот и все.

Comment: попробуйте так, я изминил код. должен работать на всех машинах

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__) == __DIR__ ` ;)

Comment: ответ помог? поставте галочку возле ответа